# Debugging PHP library code with xdebug from PhpStorm when the code is executing on a virtual machine

Tags: php, virtual-machine, phpstorm, xdebug

I have code on my local machine which IntelliJ / PhpStorm can see, and I have the same code executing inside Apache on a virtual machine.

I have remote debugging working fine and hitting breakpoints when I hit my CodeIgniter controller using zero configuration remote debugging. But, when I try to step into code that uses a require_once(), the breakpoint doesn't get hit.

It looks to be something like path mapping issues.

The local directory layout is along these lines:

```
- root_directory
  - libraries_named_differently
  - calling_code_same_name
```

The virtual machine directory layout is along these lines:

```
- root_directory
  - libraries_with_a_different_name
  - calling_code_same_name
```

I wonder if the libraries folder having a different name on the virtual machine and locally is causing any path mapping issues.

I highly doubt this has anything to do with CodeIgniter by the way.

For example, in a CodeIgniter controller where breakpoints are working fine, I load a library using:

```
require_once('/var/www/libraries/ClassExample.php');
```

Then I have a controller method in CodeIgniter like this:

```
public function endpoint {
   $hello = 'world';  // debugger works here, breakpoint hit
   $instance = new ClassExample();
   $instance->someMethod(); // <-- the debugger does not hit breakpoints inside someMethod, although I can see them being executed in the call stack view inside IntelliJ.
}
```

The path `/var/www/libraries` does *not* exist on my local machine, only on the virtual machine.

I thought a symlink from where my libraries directory is on my local machine to the `/var/www/libraries` directory would solve it, but it did not.

How can I get these breakpoints to activate in my other dependent projects?

Comment: 1) IDE has to have an access to file that currently executed in order to debug it. For that you have to copy that file into your project (or reference it in any other way so that IDE can read such file). 2) You will have to specify separate path mapping for such folder if it greatly differs from the path where main code is located (or if symbolic links are used). You have to remember that xdebug **always** works with final/resolved paths while IDE treats symlinks just like any text editor.

Comment: Thanks, I added the directory layout on both the local machine and the virtual machine.

Comment: Well -- the name does not make the difference as long as you provide correct path mappings at THAT level (I mean: you can map `/some/abc` to `/another/abc` with no issues -- as long as 1) IDE has access to local files and 2) remote path is correct and is final (no symlinks in it). if anything -- try collecting xdebug logs and see into it: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: thanks!  I'll poke around at the xdebug logs later.  I'm just doing error_log calls for debugging at the moment - not my favorite thing but moving me forward.